# Python3: split up list and save as file - how to?

Tags: list, python-3.x, split

I'm kinda new to Python, so thx for your help!

I want to tell Python to take a big .csv list and split it up to many small lists of only two columns

1. Take this .csv file
2. Always use column "year" which is the first column
3. Then take always the next column (for-loop?), starting with column 2 which is "Object1", then column 3 which is "Object2" and so on...
4. Save each list as .csv - now only containing two columns - and name it after the second column (f.e. "Object1")

So far I am up to this:

```
import csv
object = 0

f = open("/home/Data/data.csv")

csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')

writer = csv.writer(csv_f)

for row in csv_f:
    writer("[0],[object]")

    object += 1

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to open the same file for reading and writing, which may have unexpected results.

Think about your problem as a series of steps; one way to approach the problem is:

1. Open the big file
2. Read the first line of the file, which contains the column titles.
3. Go through the column titles (the first line of your big csv file), skipping the first one, then:

   1. For each column title, create a new csv file, where the filename is the name of the column.
   2. Take the value of the first column, plus the value of the column you are currently reading, and write it to the file.
   3. Repeat till all column titles are read
   4. Close the file
4. Close the big file.

Here is the same approach as above, taking advantage of Python's csv reading capabilities:

```
import csv

with open('big-file.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
   titles = next(reader)
   for index, column_name in enumerate(titles[1:]):
      with open('{}.csv'.format(column_name), 'w') as i:
         writer = csv.writer(i, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
         for row in reader:
            writer.writerow((row[0],row[index+1]))
      f.seek(0) # start from the top of the big file again
      next(reader) # skip the header column
```